# When can we say elements of tensor product are equal to $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am learning about tensor products of modules, but there is a question which makes me very confused about it!

If $E$ is a right $R$-module and $F$ is a left $R$-module, then suppose we have a balanced map (or bilinear map) $E\times F\to E\otimes F$. If some element $x\otimes y \in E\otimes F$ is $0$, then can we say $x$ or $y$ must be equal to $0$? I know if $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, then $x\otimes y$ is $0$. Are there other cases where $x\otimes y$ is $0$? Can someone give me a specific example?

Really thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the sentence beginning "If some elements..." I think you're asking whether $x\otimes y$ can be zero if $x$ and $y$ are not zero. If this is the case, I have given an answer below. If you intended to ask a different question, please edit your post to make it clear.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean!

Comment: Given that is what you intended to ask, I have edited your question in the hopes of making your question clear. Feel free to change it back if I have misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: You might also be interested in the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044952/when-are-two-simple-tensors-m-otimes-n-and-m-otimes-n-equal-tensor-pro?rq=1

Comment: (2) on Page 12 is helpful: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By the universal property of tensor product, an elementary tensor $x\otimes y$ equals zero if and only if for every $R$-bilinear map $B:E\times F\to M$, $B(x,y)=0$. While this may seem like a difficult thing to check, in practice it is usually not so bad.

As an example, we will show that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}=0$. Let $x\otimes y\in\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$ be an elementary tensor. Then by the bilinearity of the canonical map $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$, we have
$$
x\otimes y=x\otimes 5y/5=5(x\otimes y/5)=5x\otimes y/5=0\otimes y/5=0.
$$
This shows that all elementary tensors are zero, and thus since the tensor product is generated by elementary tensors, $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}=0$.

We can show that an elementary tensor $x\otimes y$ is nonzero by giving an $R$-bilinear map $B:E\times F\to M$ such that $B(x,y)\neq 0$. As an example, consider $E=F=\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and the $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear map $B:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by multiplication: $B(x,y)=xy$. Then if $x,y\neq 0$, $B(x,y)\neq 0$, so that $x\otimes y\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}$ when $x,y\neq 0$.

Comment: This is helpful when showing $m\otimes n=0$ but it is hard to use this to show $m\otimes n$ is not zero.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer to give an example of showing that $m\otimes n\neq 0$.

Comment: @dfsfljn How does the universal property guarantee that if and only if statement with which you started?

Comment: @dfsfljn, how did you do $ \ 5(x \otimes y/5)=5x \otimes y$ ?   Is it like $a B(x,y)=B(ax,ay)$ ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR that is a mistake, it should be $5x\otimes y/5$

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to find a nice characterization of when simple tensors are zero.

To give an example where $a, b$ are nonzero but $a\otimes b=0$, consider $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\otimes_\Bbb Z \Bbb Z$ where $2\otimes 3=2\cdot3\otimes 1=0\otimes 1=0$.

Comment: In $M \otimes_R N$, a simple tensor $m \otimes n$ is zero exactly when all $R$-bilinear maps $M \times N \rightarrow P$ from $M \times N$ to $R$-modules vanish on $(m,n)$.  For example, a $\mathbf Z$-bilinear map $B \colon \mathbf Z/(6) \times \mathbf Z \rightarrow A$ to a $\mathbf Z$-module $A$ (that is, an abelian group $A$) has $B(2,3) = 3B(2,1) = B(6,1) = B(0,1) = 0$. This is related to your example that $2 \otimes 3 = 0$ in $\mathbf Z/(6) \otimes_{\mathbf Z} \mathbf Z$.

Comment: @KCd Yes, that’s true! But I think when I wrote this, the bar I had in mind for what would count as “a nice way” was more along the lines of “just by looking at it”.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while seeking to answer a related one. I think it's worth saying that $0\otimes n = (0\cdot 0)\otimes n = 0\cdot(0\otimes n) = 0\otimes(0\cdot 0) = 0\otimes 0 = 0\in M\otimes_A N$ where $M$ and $N$ are left $A$-modules (or right--I can never remember which is which).

(You may also note that $0\cdot n = (1 + (-1))\cdot n = n - n = 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

To add to other good answers and comments: perhaps a one slightly abstracted version of the question can be construed as asking about the *exactness* of the tensor product functor(s) $M\to M\otimes N$. This is not an exact functor (in many interesting categories), and its failure to be exact is measured by "Tor" groups (which are also construable as derived functors, apart from specific explicit constructions in various categories). In particular, at the very least, ${\mathrm Tor}^i(M,N)$ is very often non-zero even for $i=1$.

In different words: it is a non-trivial problem, with no simple general formulaic solution, to find the collapsing/relations in tensor products. And there are many well-known examples with some at-first-possibly-surprising collapsing, as mentioned already, as $\mathbb Z/m\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z/n\approx \mathbb Z/\gcd(m,n)$.