# Quotienting by an ideal in tensor product of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

All rings are commutative ring with unity.

Let $A$ and $B$ are two $R$-algebras and $I$ and $J$ are two ideals of $A$ and $B$ respectively. I want to show that $A\otimes_R B/(I\otimes_R B+A\otimes_R J)\cong (A/I)\otimes_R (B/J)$.

Theres is a map from $A\otimes_R B/(I\otimes_R B+A\otimes_R J)$ to $(A/I)\otimes_R (B/J)$ (as $I\otimes_R B+A\otimes_R J$ is in the kernel of the map $A\otimes_R B\rightarrow  (A/I)\otimes_R (B/J))$ and this map is also surjective. But how would I show that this is also an injective map?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd consider the canonical epimorphism

$$A\otimes_R B\rightarrow (A/I)\otimes_R (B/J): a\otimes b\rightarrow (a+I)\otimes (b+J)$$

and show that the kernel is

$$I\otimes_R B + A\otimes_R J.$$

Then the result follows from the first isomorphism theorem.

It is clear that $I\otimes_R B + A\otimes_R J$ lies in the kernel. Let $a\otimes b$ be in the kernel, i.e., $(a+I)\otimes (b+J) = 0$. Please consider 
[When can we say elements of tensor product are equal to $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686568/when-can-we-say-elements-of-tensor-product-are-equal-to-0)

Comment: My question is why this is the kernel? It is clear that $I\otimes_RB+A\otimes_R J$ is in the kernel.

Comment: Your link is insufficient. It only covers vanishing of **pure** tensors.

Comment: However, it is true that the kernel is $I \otimes_R B + A \otimes_R J$. This follows, e.g., from Theorem 2.19 in [Keith Conrad's *Tensor Products II*](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf), or from Theorem 18 in [my *A few classical results on tensor, symmetric and exterior powers*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/tensorext.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}\DeclareMathOperator\Ker{Ker}$
Let $\alpha:A\to A/I$ and $\beta:B\to B/J$ be the canonical projections.
Then $\alpha\otimes_B\beta:A\otimes_RB\to(A/I)\otimes_R(B/J)$ is surjective as composition of surjective homomorphisms.
A diagram chasing on the diagram below shows $\Ker(\alpha\otimes_R\beta)=\Ker(\alpha\otimes_R1_B)+\Ker(1_A\otimes_R\beta)$.
$\begin{CD}
@. A\otimes_RJ\\
@. @VVV\\
I\otimes_RB@>>>A\otimes_RB@>>>(A/I)\otimes_RB@>>>\{0\}\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
I\otimes_R(B/J)@>>>A\otimes_R(B/J) @>>>(A/I)\otimes_R(B/J)@>>>\{0\}\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\{0\} @. \{0\} @. \{0\}\\
\end{CD}$