# $a\otimes b=0$ in $A\otimes_R B$. Then $(a, b)$ is a combination of some basis elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring with 1, $A$ a right $R$-module and $B$ a left $R$-module. To construct their tensor product, let $F$ be the free abelian group with basis $A\times B$ and $S$ the subgroup generated by all elements of the following three types : $(a,b+b')-(a,b)-(a,b'); (a+a',b)-(a,b)-(a',b); (ar,b)-(a,rb)$. Then $A\otimes_R B=F/S$.

Let $a\otimes b=0$. Then $(a,b)\in S$. So $(a,b)$ can be written as $\sum\limits_{k}\pm(a_k,b_k),$ where $a_k\in A, b_k\in B$ and $a_k$ are $a,a+a',ar$ and $b_k$ are $b,b+b',rb$.

I was wondering if the last sentence is correct.

Comment: For me, this is the definition of $A\otimes_RB$. Which definition do you have?

Comment: I was just wondering as I saw the expression $\sum\limits_{k}\pm(a_k,b_k)$ without $\pm$. I thought $-$sign could appear because of the form of elements generating $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(a,b) \in S$ it can be written in such a way but you also have the fact that $A \times B$ is a basis of the free abelian group $F$. Thus since $(a,b) \in A \times B$ it is already uniquely written in this basis. Hence every element of your sum must have its opposite somewhere in the sum too, except for one which would be $(a,b)$.

A word of warning, this does not mean that $a=0$ or $b=0$. For example if there is some torsion in the module or some zero divisor in the ring:
$$(ra,b)=(ra,b)-(a,rb) + (a,0) -(0\times a,0) \in S \ \text{ if } rb=0$$

You can find a more complete answer (with a caracterisation and some examples) about this warning [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1686576/743994).