# Tor functor on a torsion ring

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Suppose $R$ is a Ring and $B$ is a $R-$ module. Define $_{r}R=\left\{s\in S | rs=0 \right\}$. If $_{r}R$ is not zero, we have an exact sequence: $$ 0\rightarrow _{r}R \rightarrow R \xrightarrow {\text{times r}} R \rightarrow R/rR \rightarrow 0$$. Prove that we have an exact sequence:$$0\rightarrow Tor_{2}^{R}(R/rR,B)\rightarrow _{r}R\otimes B\rightarrow _{r}B \rightarrow Tor_{1}^{R}(R/rR,B)\rightarrow 0$$ and $Tor_{n}^{R}(R/rR,B)\cong Tor_{n-2}^{R}(_{r}R,B)$ for $n>3$.

Things are quite simple when $_{r}R=0$, because the first exact sequence would become projective resolution of $R/rR$. But now it's not projective resolution. From the outlook of the result we have to prove, it seems to me that we have to find new projective resolutions for both $R/rR$ and $R/rR$ which are somehow related to the given exact sequence. I had a hard time finding projective resolutions for these two objects.

Comment: You don't need projective resolutions. Just split the 4 terms exact sequence in two : 
$$ 0\to{_rR}\to R\to M\to 0$$
$$ 0\to M\to R\to R/rR$$
then use the long exact sequences associated to these two short exact sequence.

Comment: Alternatively, use the more advanced method exposed here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705108/how-to-write-long-exact-sequence-as-short-exact-sequence-of-complex (a 2 days old topic...)

Comment: @Roland The first $M$ is $R/_{r}R$ and the second $M$ is $rR$. Am I correct? How can these two short exact sequences be related in order to give the desired result?

Comment: The point is that this is the same $M$ (and I don't even need to say what it is). This is a general method when you have a long exact sequence (sequence with at least 4 terms), it is called splitting a long exact sequence. If you have a sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to D\to 0$, you can split it in $$0\to A\to B\to M\to 0$$ $$0\to M\to C\to D\to 0$$ with $$M=\ker (C\to D)=\operatorname{Im}(B\to C)=B/\ker(B\to C)=B/\operatorname{Im}(A\to B)=\operatorname{coker}(A\to B)$$

Comment: @Roland Really Thank you for your help with which I finally solve it with the full detail.